# GCM Unauthorized Error 401

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, sails.js

I'm not able to get response from GCM even i'm providing correct server API key generated by google.

Problem : I want to make a push notification using GCM from my sails app.
I'm posting below code to "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send"

Code : 1

```
{
  "headers":{
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
    "Authorization":"key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
 "notification":{
   "title":"Hello Notify",
   "text":"Notification By Sails"
 },
 "registration_ids":["xxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxx"]
}
```

Code : 2

```
{
  "headers":{
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
    "Authorization":"key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
 "body":{
   "notification":{
      "title":"Hello Notify",
      "text":"Notification By Sails"
    }
  },
 "registration_ids":["xxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxx"]
}
```

I'm getting response as below.

```
"statusCode": 401,
"body": "<HTML>\n
           <HEAD>\n<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n
           <BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\" TEXT=\"#000000\">\n
               <H1>Unauthorized</H1>\n
               <H2>Error 401</H2>\n
           </BODY>\n
         </HTML>\n",
```

Answer (score 2):

The headers should be HTTP headers, not element in the payload.

Comment: The example here should more inline to what you want to achieve: http://code.runnable.com/U4kVi8yKO58ptG0l/%5Bandroid-api%5D-gcm-send-using-node-js

Comment: @DebuggerCoder curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Authorization:key=AIzaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" --data-ascii '{"notification":{"body":"yyy"},"to":"XXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY-ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"}'

Comment: @DebuggerCoder also, use "body" attribute instead of "text"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled the right API in [Cloud Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). If sending with a Server API key, you need to have "Google Cloud Messaging for Android" enabled.

[image: A screenshot from Cloud Console]